# PHP : !in_array not working with empty array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i'm facing some problem with my code , here is the sample of my code

```
$arr2=array();
$element1="2015-01-13";

if(!in_array($element1,$arr2)) {
         array_push($arr2,$element1);
}

var_dump($arr2);
```

output is a empty array

```
array(0) {
}
```

if the array already have a element(added by manually), say 2015-01-12 , then 2015-03-13 was successfully inserted by array push.

what is happening when array is empty and cheking with in_array .?

**Here is the original Code**

```
$arr2 = array();                    // ARRAY UNIQUE PROCESS TO PREDATES

        foreach($predates as $element1)
            {
                foreach($predates as $element2)
                    {

                        if ($element1 != $element2 && !in_array($element1,$arr2))
                            {
                                array_push($arr2,$element1);
                                                                    echo "enter";
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was that code pasted correctly? It gives me a parse error because there is no dollar sign at the beginning of "element1". In fact, when I fix that error it works for me. I get `array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2015-01-13" }`.

Comment: And when I add the missing `$` in, it prints out an array with the correct value in it.

Comment: Does the array_push get called Can you put an echo "hi" inside the if() to see if it's the in_array or the array_push what is failing?

Comment: I think you rushing to post a question in stackoverflow... this is not a real question. Learn how to type a correct syntax!!

Comment: sorry for mistakes in question, the questions is updated with original code

Comment: Why are you looping through `prefaces` n^2 times? Why not just `$arr2 = array_unique($predates)`?

Comment: @ShifanaMubi - thank you for the update, but that code also seems to work as expected. Are you sure that you're setting `$predates` correctly?

Comment: Everything works correctly. Please avoid of using n^2 runtimes as @h2ooooooo said.

Comment: yes print_r($predates) outputs some dates from mysql(all the date are same) . and i used this loop instead of array_uniqe($predates); because i want to use this dates in another part of code

Comment: @ShifanaMubi Can you update your example with the output from `print_r($predates)` and what you're expecting from it in `$arr2`?

Comment: i used this loop for taking unique date from a collection of repeating different dates. hre is print_r($predates) = Array ( [0] => 2015-01-13 [1] => 2015-01-13 [2] => 2015-01-13 [3] => 2015-01-13 ) 2015-01-13=2015-01-13

Comment: your edit code will do no thing if `$predates` size is less than `2` other wise it will copy the `$predates` to `$arr2` What you actually want?

Comment: i want unique date in $arr2 , $predates contains same dates 2015-01-13, 2015-01-13, same etc at this condition. i want to push only one date to $ arr2

Comment: @ShifanaMubi Like I wrote; `$arr2 = array_unique($predates);`.

Comment: Thank you  h2ooooooo for your helping mentality even my question was wrong, i got my output :) i posted it as an answer to my own question :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello i am glad to help you out,

what is happening here is a combination of 2 factors...

1. you are missing a $ on your   `$element` variable
2. you do not have all your error reporting activated so the notice is not been shown on screen , or you are using a framework wich modifies `error_reporting` so the notice is skipped.

I strongly recommend you to always look at the `/var/log/httpd/error_log` for debugging your code and use `error_reporting = E_ALL` for debugging task , 
regards

Comment: i already said it is a sample code in my question, the problem not with $ sign, anyway thanks for your reply. please do not down vote this queston, i'm beginner to php

Comment: @ShifanaMubi please explain what you are trying to accomplish with new code you posted cause i made my test and it is working... i ll be glad to help you out

Comment: Thank you DiegoCoderPlus for your kindness, i got my output :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my all mistakes, finally i founded the problem and solved it .

The Problem is here:

```
if ($element1 != $element2 && !in_array($element1,$arr2))
```

if the dates are same , then element1 and element2 is same and i used && operator inside.so it will not enter to the loop. but && is mandatory because if all dates are different then all of them pushed into array more than one.

The solution is :

```
if (count(array_unique($predates))===1) {
                              array_push($arr2,$predates[1]);
                         }
```

this loop will check all the array elements are same, then insert 1st element
and `if ($element1 != $element2 && !in_array($element1,$arr2))` still there, i got my output.

plese downvote this answer, it my kindly request